# Inheriting Handles From Parent Processes in Windows

Tags: c++, windows

In Windows 7, when would a child process want to inherit the process handle or the thread handle of the parent processes? What would this be useful for/accomplish? Thanks.

Comment: Makes no sense, a child process gets its own process handle and must create its own threads.

Comment: @HansPassant: I assume he is talking about handle inheritance. In which case it is possible to pass process and thread handles from a parent to child process via `DuplicateHandle`. Of course, that assign those handles to the child, but just makes it valid for that process. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724466(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use it, to wait for the parent process to terminate, see for example [WaitForSingleObjectEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).